# r: Delete the whole group if it contains duplicate values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of sets containing different colours.  If duplicates exist within the set then I want to delete the whole set.

For instance, in the following example data, set 1 contains the colours red, red, yellow, so I want to delete set 1.

```
Set  Colour
Set1 red
Set1 red
Set1 yellow
Set2 green
Set2 blue
Set2 red
Set3 yellow
Set3 yellow
Set3 blue
Set3 yellow
```

I only want to keep set 2 as it only contains colours that appear once in the group.

Data:

```
structure(list(Set = c("Set1", "Set1", "Set1", "Set2", "Set2", 
"Set2", "Set3", "Set3", "Set3", "Set3"), Colour = c("red", "red", 
"yellow", "green", "blue", "red", "yellow", "yellow", "blue", 
"yellow")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it this way

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(Set) %>% 
  filter(n_distinct(Colour) == n())


  Set   Colour
  <chr> <chr> 
1 Set2  green 
2 Set2  blue  
3 Set2  red
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)


df <- df[, .SD[anyDuplicated(Colour)==0], by = Set]
#     Set Colour
# 1: Set2  green
# 2: Set2   blue
# 3: Set2    red


# Convert back to data.frame with setDF(df)
```

Combining with `ave()` inspired by Allan Cameron

```
df[ave(Colour, Set, FUN=anyDuplicated)==0] # data.table
filter(df, ave(Colour, Set, FUN=anyDuplicated)==0) # dplyr
subset(df, ave(Colour, Set, FUN=anyDuplicated)==0) # Base R
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R you could do:

```r
subset(df, ave(Colour, Set, FUN=anyDuplicated) == 0)
#>    Set Colour
#> 4 Set2  green
#> 5 Set2   blue
#> 6 Set2    red
```

(with thanks to sindri baldur for the improvement on my original)

or

```r
subset(df, Set==names(which(tapply(Colour,Set, function(x) !any(duplicated(x))))))
#>    Set Colour
#> 4 Set2  green
#> 5 Set2   blue
#> 6 Set2    red
```

or

```r
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$Set), 
                      function(x) if(nrow(x) == length(unique(x$Colour))) x))
#>         Set Colour
#> Set2.4 Set2  green
#> Set2.5 Set2   blue
#> Set2.6 Set2    red
```

Comment: Also `subset(df, ave(Colour, Set, FUN=anyDuplicated)==0)`

Comment: Ooh that's nice @sindri_baldur.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach. You can compute the number of observations per `Set` and `Colour` in a new variable then as you want the non duplicated sets you can use `any()` to test any observation greater than one and then filter only the values with an unique value. Here the code (I have used your data as `df`):

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
df %>% group_by(Set,Colour) %>%
  mutate(N=n()) %>% ungroup() %>%
  group_by(Set) %>%
  mutate(Var=any(N>1)) %>%
  filter(!Var) %>% select(-c(N,Var))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   Set [1]
  Set   Colour
  <chr> <chr> 
1 Set2  green 
2 Set2  blue  
3 Set2  red
```